# Draw 2d layered map javascript

Tags: javascript, 2d, layer, tiles

im building an 2d rpg game in javascript and using canvas,a bit like browserquest.

I know how to draw a simple 2d array to show a single layered tile map to the canvas.

But to get a better effect when the player is moving around etc i want to be able to create a layered tile map in Tiled. I was thinking of these layers:

background layer to hold ground information and grass,rocks etc

player/object layer to hold info for where the player is and where objects are.

collision layer to hold bits of where the user will and wont collide.

foreground layer to hold tiles where the player can move behind ie. tree tops, and house tops etc.

Does this sound ok?

My question:

How would i load the map data saved as JSON from tiled map editor? 
And then how do i use this information to display it on the canvas?

Also how would i check details on on layers from my player level? e.g how would i check for collisions when they are in a different layer?

Thanks in advance for any help

Tom

EDIT: i have created a json tilemap from using TILED:

```
{ "height":15,
 "layers":[
    {
     "data":[79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 28, 29, 30, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 28, 29, 30, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 28, 29, 30, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 28, 29, 30, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 111, 29, 30, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 28, 29, 128, 45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 28, 29, 30, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 28, 29, 30, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 111, 29, 112, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 79, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 79, 28, 29, 128, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 79, 28, 29, 30, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 28, 29, 30, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 28, 29, 30, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79],
     "height":15,
     "name":"background",
     "opacity":1,
     "type":"tilelayer",
     "visible":true,
     "width":20,
     "x":0,
     "y":0
    }, 
    {
     "data":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 149, 150, 151, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 165, 166, 167, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 168, 0, 0, 0, 181, 182, 183, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 168, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 222, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 237, 0, 0, 0, 245, 246, 247, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 152, 0, 0, 0, 168, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 152, 222, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 168, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 149, 150, 151, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 165, 166, 167, 0, 0, 0, 152, 0, 237, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 245, 246, 247, 0, 168, 181, 182, 183],
     "height":15,
     "name":"background_objects",
     "opacity":1,
     "type":"tilelayer",
     "visible":true,
     "width":20,
     "x":0,
     "y":0
    }, 
    {
     "height":15,
     "name":"collisions",
     "objects":[
            {
             "height":32,
             "name":"",
             "properties":
                {

                },
             "type":"",
             "visible":true,
             "width":100,
             "x":-3,
             "y":192
            }, 
            {
             "height":31,
             "name":"",
             "properties":
                {

                },
             "type":"",
             "visible":true,
             "width":32,
             "x":159,
             "y":448
            }, 
            {
             "height":30,
             "name":"",
             "properties":
                {

                },
             "type":"",
             "visible":true,
             "width":94,
             "x":385,
             "y":448
            }, 
            {
             "height":31,
             "name":"",
             "properties":
                {

                },
             "type":"",
             "visible":true,
             "width":33,
             "x":511,
             "y":160
            }, 
            {
             "height":27,
             "name":"",
             "properties":
                {

                },
             "type":"",
             "visible":true,
             "width":32,
             "x":320,
             "y":258
            }, 
            {
             "height":30,
             "name":"",
             "properties":
                {

                },
             "type":"",
             "visible":true,
             "width":31,
             "x":128,
             "y":97
            }],
     "opacity":1,
     "type":"objectgroup",
     "visible":true,
     "width":20,
     "x":0,
     "y":0
    }, 
    {
     "data":[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 206, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 197, 198, 199, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 213, 214, 215, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 221, 0, 0, 0, 229, 230, 231, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 206, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 197, 198, 199, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 213, 214, 215, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 221, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 229, 230, 231, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     "height":15,
     "name":"foreground",
     "opacity":1,
     "type":"tilelayer",
     "visible":true,
     "width":20,
     "x":0,
     "y":0
    }],
 "orientation":"orthogonal",
 "properties":
{

},
 "tileheight":32,
 "tilesets":[
    {
     "firstgid":1,
     "image":"..\/..\/..\/..\/..\/..\/..\/xampp\/htdocs\/DIS\/images\/mountain_landscape_23.png",
     "imageheight":512,
     "imagewidth":512,
     "margin":0,
     "name":"level_1",
     "properties":
        {

        },
     "spacing":0,
     "tileheight":32,
     "tilewidth":32
    }],
 "tilewidth":32,
 "version":1,
 "width":20
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The javascript framework "Melon JS" can import Tiled TMX maps. It would be best to use something like that (rather than reinventing the wheel). Here's a link:

http://www.melonjs.org/

Comment: im actually building my own engine, hence why i would like this information, thanks

Comment: You can still use Melon JS to load the TMX file into an object model, but render it using your own engine. I had a quick look at TMX files and found that they are fairly complex, hence this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

@Chris Nash thanks for your suggestions!

I have found a tutorial on loading in layered tilemaps using JSON from tiled which i think i am going to follow.

In case anyone w[Json loader for tiled map editor](http://blog.hashrocket.com/posts/using-tiled-and-canvas-to-render-game-screens)